# How to avoid creating a class attribute by accident

Tags: python-3.x

I know the motto is "we're all consenting adults around here."

but here is a problem I spent a day on.  I got passed a class with over 100 attributes.  I had specified one of them was to be called "run_count".  The front-end had a place to enter run_count.

Somehow, the front-end/back-end package people decided to call it "run_iterations" instead.

So, my problem is I am writing unit test software, and I did this:

```
passed_parameters.run_count = 100
result = do_the_thing(passed_parameters)
assert result == 99.75
```

Now, the problem, of course, is that Python willingly let me set this "new" attribute called "run_count".  But, after delving 10 levels down into the code, I discover that the function "do_the_thing" (obviously) never looks at "run_count", but uses "passed_paramaters.run_iterations" instead.

Is there some simple way to avoid allowing yourself to create a new attribute in a class, or a new entry in a dictionary, when you naievely assume you know the attribute name (or the dict key), and accidentally create a new entry that never gets looked at?

In an ideal world, no matter how dynamic, Python would allow you to "lock" and object or instance of one.  Then, trying to set a new value for an attribute that doesn't exist would raise an attribute error, letting you know you are trying to change something that doesn't exist, rather than letting you create a new attribute that never gets used.

Comment: It seems you are looking for an statically typed language

Comment: No, just looking for a way to avoid wasted time on complex projects.  As I noted, most of the dat went into tracking down what attribute - other than the one I had asked for - got specified on the front-end and used deep in the back-end, where it was not what I expected.  This is a nightmare for large projects: suppose you develop a class, someone redefines an attribute or method for it that changes it but their code relies on it, but that def changes later.  It would be a nightmare to track down that what got lost was someone's redefinition you never knew of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `__setattr__`, and check the attribute exists, otherwise, throw an error. If you do this, you will receive an error when you define those attributes inside `__init__`, so you have to workaround that situation. I found 4 ways of doing that. First, define those attributes inside the class, that way, when you try to set their initial value they will already be defined. Second, call `object.__setattr__` directly. Third, add a fourth boolean param to `__setattr__` indicating whether to bypass checking or not. Fourth, define the previous boolean flag as class-wide, set it to `True`, initialize the fields and set the flag back to `False`. Here is the code:

### Code

```python
class A:
  f = 90
  a = None

  bypass_check = False

  def __init__(self, a, b, c, d1, d2, d3, d4):
    # 1st workaround
    self.a = a

    # 2nd workaround
    object.__setattr__(self, 'b', b)

    # 3rd workaround
    self.__setattr__('c', c, True)

    # 4th workaround
    self.bypass_check = True 
    self.d1 = d1
    self.d2 = d2
    self.d3 = d3
    self.d4 = d4
    self.bypass_check = False

  def __setattr__(self, attr, value, bypass=False):
    if bypass or self.bypass_check or hasattr(self, attr):
      object.__setattr__(self, attr, value)
    else:
      # Throw some error
      print('Attribute %s not found' % attr)

a = A(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
a.f = 100
a.d1 = -1
a.g = 200
print(a.f, a.a, a.d1, a.d4)
```

### Output

```
Attribute g not found
100 1 -1 7
```

Comment: In the right area, but how to avoid accidentally creating new attributes, not calling for ones that don't exiist?

Comment: It seems there ought to be a __setattr__(), and one could put a hook in there.  Something like:  def __set_attr__(attr, value): if not __get_attr__(attr) raise <proper error> else <go and__setattr__()>

Comment: @eSurfsnake please, remember to mark my answer as accepted (green checkmark) and up vote it if this worked for you. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Whoops - one problem.  Try your code with an __init__ method.  It won't let you set values for attributes in the class; 'self.a = a' throws the error.  The way you did it, you created a class-wide var f, but that doesn't really solve the problem.

Comment: One possible workaround could be to declare/define the fields in the class (like `f`) and define `__init__` in the normal way, passing in the values for those fields. That way, the fields will already be there and not undefined. You could also bypass `__setattr__` and call `object.__setattr__` directly: ```object.__setattr__(self, 'g', 500)``` inside `__init__` or add a fourth boolean param to `__setattr__` with a default value of `False` indicating whether to bypass checking or not: ```def __setattr__(self, attr, value, bpass=False)``` and call it ```self.__setattr__('g', 500, True)```

Comment: @eSurfsnake I edited the code and added a few workarounds for such situations.