# Can you "force" a method into a class from outside?

Tags: python-3.x

I am working with a large class I didn't define.  At least as far as my code goes, I would like to make it impossible to give an instance of that class new attributes, which Python willingly allows.

Were I the maintainer of the class I could easily get that done (see: [How to avoid creating a class attribute by accident](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53967220/how-to-avoid-creating-a-class-attribute-by-accident/53967301?noredirect=1#comment94772369_53967301)).

Now, as much as I am complaining about injecting new things into a class, I would like to inject the logic in that answer into the class (or its instances I get).  in other words, something like:

```
object.__setattr__(a,'x',print("here is x."))
```

So the object has a method 'x()' that does the print (actually, I want to insert the logic from the answer I posted, so I want to modify **set_attr**() from the outside, as it were. to give me that control over new attributes being set.)

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you just write a subclass?

Comment: Or monkeypatch the class to override `__setattr__`?

Comment: I think that is what I am trying to do - monkey patch the class.  But, how would you do that?  Python is pretty consistent that everything is a class, but as far as I can tell it makes a distinction between attributes (which have a class) and methods (i.e., code).  Methods have a 'def' statement, which I can't figure out how to 'inject' from the outside.  This is unlike Lisp, for example, where code and data are indistinguishable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out surprisingly easy to do to force a function into (at least an instance) of a Python class.  This code:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def sum(self):
        return self.a + self.b

a = A(2,3)
print(a.sum())

def zz(self):
    return self.b - self.a

z = lambda : zz(a)
a.z = z

print(a.z())
```

gives this output, as expected:

```
$ python3 inject-function.py 
5
1
```